# web console to debug HTTP calls with JSOn paylod and JSON replies

Tags: web-apps, http, json

I am looking for software (ideally a browser plugin) which would be a web console allowing me to query (`GET`, `POST`, ...) a remote server with some `JSON` payload, and display the response (which is also going to be `JSON`).

This could be something similar to [`Sense`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en) (the plugin version)

Comment: I understand why you would prefer a plugin but for the occasional request check out: https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: @User: nice find, thanks, but this will not allow to make calls to internal networks (10.x)

Comment: Ah.  See also [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) and [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) chrome extensions.